# How to insert a string to a text field using mechanize in ruby?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize, nomethoderror

I know is a very simple question but I've been stuck for an hour and I just can't understand how this works.

I need to scrape some stuff from my school's library so I need to insert 'CE' to a text field and then click on a link with text 'Clasificación'. The output is what I am going to use to work. So here is my code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

url = 'http://biblio02.eld.edu.mx/janium-bin/busqueda_rapida.pl?Id=20110720161008#'
searchStr = 'CE'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)

searchForm = page.form_with(:method => 'post')
searchForm['buscar'] = searchStr

clasificacionLink = page.link_with(:href => "javascript:onClick=set_index_and_submit(\'51\');").click
page = agent.submit(searchForm,clasificacionLink)
```

When I run it, it gives me this error

```
janium.rb:31: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mu's answer sounds reasonable.  I am not sure if this is strictly necessary, but you might also try to put braces around `searchStr`.

```
searchForm['buscar'] = [searchStr]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is actually on line 13, not 31, and I'll even tell why I think that. Not only does your script not have 31 lines but, from the [fine manual](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-form_with-28criteria-29):

> **form_with(criteria)**
>   Find a single form matching criteria.

There are several forms on that page that have `method="post"`. Apparently Mechanize returns `nil` when it can't exactly match the `form_with` criteria including the *single* part mentioned in the documentation; so, if your `criteria` matches more than one thing, `form_with` returns `nil` instead of choosing one of the options and you end up trying to do this:

```
nil['buscar'] = searchStr
```

But `nil` doesn't have a `[]=` method so you get your `NoMethodError`.

If you use this:

```
searchForm = page.form_with(:name => 'forma')
```

you'll get past the first part as there is exactly one form with `name="forma"` on that page. Then you'll have trouble with this:

```
clasificacionLink = page.link_with(:href => "javascript:onClick=set_index_and_submit(\'51\');").click
page = agent.submit(searchForm, clasificacionLink)
```

as Mechanize doesn't know what to do with JavaScript (at least mine doesn't). But if you use just this:

```
page = agent.submit(searchForm)
```

you'll get a `page` and then you can continue building and debugging your script.